# How can I plot a dataframe in R given in quarterly years?

Tags: r, time, time-series, series

i have a dataset given with:

```
   Country Time      Value
1   USA    1999-Q1   292929
2   USA    1999-Q2   392023
3.  USA    1999-Q3   9392992
4
```

.... and so on. Now I would like to plot this dataframe with Time being on the x-axis and y being the Value. But the problem I face is I dont know how to plot the Time. Because it is not given in month/date/year. If that would be the case I would just code `as.Date( format = "%m%d%y")`. I am not allowed to change the quarterly name. So when I plot it, it should stay that way. How can I do this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming DF shown in the Note at the end, convert the Time column to `yearqtr` class which directly represents year and quarter (as opposed to using `Date` class) and use `scale_x_yearqtr`.   See `?scale_x_yearqtr` for more information.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(zoo)

fmt <- "%Y-Q%q"
DF$Time <- as.yearqtr(DF$Time, format = fmt)
ggplot(DF, aes(Time, Value, col = Country)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_yearqtr(format = fmt)
```

(continued after graphics)
[image: screenshot]

It would also be possible to convert it to a wide form zoo object with one column per country and then use `autoplot`.  Using `DF` from the Note below:

```
fmt <- "%Y-Q%q"
z <- read.zoo(DF, split = "Country", index = "Time", 
  FUN = as.yearqtr, format = fmt)
autoplot(z) + scale_x_yearqtr(format = fmt)
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "
Country Time Value 
1 USA 1999-Q1 292929 
2 USA 1999-Q2 392023 
3 USA 1999-Q3 9392992"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines)
```

Comment: Although I would probably do something like this if I were plotting myself, it is worth noting that the format of the Time column means that the chronological ordering and lexicographic ordering would be the same, so a conversion to a different format may just be adding complexity if all that is required is a simple plot with direct labels. Or am I missing the point?

Comment: True, though the OP did say they were not allowed to change the quarterly names, and a line plot is still possible using the group aesthetic. I don't at all disagree with your approach - I was making an observation about the factor levels happening to coincide with chronological ordering, and how that permitted a short-cut to fulfilling the OP's specifications.

Comment: @Allan, This is a time series and time series are normally plotted as lines, not as bar graphs.  Also it is unlikely that this is the only thing that needs to be done. Better to first get the data into into a reasonable form and then work with it.

Answer (score 1):

Using ggplot2:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(Time, Value, fill = Country)) + geom_col()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I know other people have already answered, but I think this more general answer should also be here.

When you do `as.Date()`, you can only do the beginning. I tried it on your data frame (I called it `df`), and it worked:

```
> as.Date(df$Time, format = "%Y")
[1] "1999-11-28" "1999-11-28" "1999-11-28"
```

Now, I don't know if you want to use `plot()`, `ggplot()`, the `ggplot2` library... I don't know that, and it doesn't matter. However you want to specify the y axis, you can do it this way.